# Aero spokes cross pattern

Tags: wheel-building

Does it make sense building a wheel using a 2 or 3 cross pattern and aero (bladed) spokes? Or are aero spokes used with radial lacing only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bladed spokes are used on rear wheels, which must have cross lacing on the drive side at least. Disc brake wheels obviously require cross lacing front and rear too.

You'll tend to see bladed spokes with low spoke count and radial lacing together because they are all elements of higher performance wheels. However,  I don't see why bladed spokes would not give some (perhaps slight) aerodynamic advantage if used on high spoke count 3-cross wheels.

Comment: *some (perhaps slight) aerodynamic advantage*.  Yep.  [It's about one watt](https://novemberbicycles.com/blogs/blog/aerodynamic-drag-of-lasers-vs-cx-rays).  For a 20-spoke radially-laced front wheel.  It's probably less for rear wheels, higher spoke counts, and crossed lacing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle How does that 1 watt compare to other wheel aero savings?  it could be quite cost effective compared to saving watts with a slightly deeper, more expensive rim for example. i.e. could it have good watts/dollar when speccing a new wheel?

Comment: @Swifty *How does that 1 watt compare to other wheel aero savings?*  [This is a good post on that.](https://novemberbicycles.com/blogs/blog/the-rail-prototype-wind-tunnel-data-and-calculations) TLDR:  Good wheels can save you up to 20W, maybe a bit more.  **If** you're a world-class rider.  If you're not that fast, they'll save you less wattage.  Yeah, 15-20W can be a big deal.  It's like increasing your threshold power from 255 to 270W.  But to get that 15-20W, you need to spend a few thousand dollars.

Comment: @AndrewHenle rear wheels tend to be running in dirty air flow, so benefit far less from bladed spokes.  Often the blades are on the front wheel where the airflow is more laminar.